# What is the leftward facing implication symbol?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to know what the latex command for the leftward facing implication symbol (an arrow with two bars) is. I'm trying to separate the 'if and only if' symbol to prove both implications, but I only know the command :

$\implies$

for the rightward implication.

Thanks!

Comment: `\Leftarrow` and `Rightarrow`

Comment: Did you try `\impliedby`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the commands distinguished capitalised letters. I now see that \leftarrow and \Leftarrow are different commands. Thanks.